# How to stop the loop after same choices?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

my code looks something like this, but i have a problem. Whenever the choices are the same the game restarts. After finishing a game I get an "undefined" alert, because the startGame() function runs again with the parameters from the first round (where the choices were the same).

I am new to the word of JS and would like to keep this as simple as possible. Can someone help me by providing a solution on how to stop the 'undefined'?

```js
// the game starts here
function startGame() {
  // the user
  var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

  // if invalid input
  while ((userChoice != "rock") && (userChoice != "paper") && (userChoice != "scissors")) {
    userChoice = prompt("Please select again, this time correctly!");
  }

  alert("You chose " + userChoice);

  // computer
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }
  alert("Computer pick: " + computerChoice);

  // comparison between user and computer
  var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {

    // if both selections are the same
    if (choice1 == choice2) {
      alert("Tie, restart the game!");
      startGame();
    }

    // if the user selects rock
    else if (choice1 == "rock") {
      if (choice2 == "scissors") {
        return "You have won the game!";
      } else {
        return "LOOOOOSSEEER!";
      }
    }

    // if the user selects scissors
    else if (choice1 == "scissors") {
      if (choice2 == "rock") {
        return "You have won the game!";
      }
    } else {
      return "LOOOOOSSEEER";
    }
  };

  alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
}

// startGame();
```

Comment: In your first `if` statement i.e. `if (choice1 == choice2) {..`, you start the game again calling `startGame();` explicitly over there. Is it not normal for the game to restart as per your code?

Comment: You should use compare function just to return the game status.. and thereafter based on its value you can either put alert or restart the startGame fn call. e.g var result = compare(ch1,ch2); if(result === "..."){...

Comment: @Amitesh Kumar  can you give me an example from my code? I am not clear with what you are trying to explain

Comment: You just made a [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). The compare function should be responsible only to return compare result and not to restart the game. You should restart the game after compare function returns 'Tie..'. Also you've missed the checks when user choose 'paper' and some of the checks are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a recursion here. The startGame() function starts again and the first call of compare() expects a return statement. But in this if clause you have no return statement at all.

```
// if both selections are the same
if (choice1 == choice2) {
  alert("Tie, restart the game!");
  startGame();
}
```

You solve this by instead of returning the result just alert withing the if statements. here is a jsfiddle (function call commented):

http://jsfiddle.net/v5poL9cm/

Edit:

Another approach is to return the message in all cases and let the startGame() function have a return statement as well. jsfiddle here (function call commented):

http://jsfiddle.net/65sg7mcL/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    startGame();
});

// the game starts here
function startGame() {
    // the user
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

    // if invalid input
    while ((userChoice != "rock") && (userChoice != "paper") && (userChoice != "scissors")) {
        userChoice = prompt("Please select again, this time correctly!");
    }

    alert("You chose " + userChoice);

    // computer
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    alert("Computer pick: " + computerChoice);

    // comparison between user and computer
    var result = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
    if (result == "1") {
        alert("Tie, restart the game!");
        startGame();
    } else if (result == "2") {
        alert("You have won the game!");
    } else {
        alert("LOOOOOSSEEER");
    }
}

// return 1 -- > Tie
// return 2 -- > You have won
// return 3 -- > LOOOOOSSEEER
function compare(choice1, choice2) {

    // if both selections are the same
    if (choice1 == choice2) {
        return "1";
    }
    // if the user selects rock
    else if (choice1 == "rock") {
        if (choice2 == "scissors") {
            return "2";
        } else {
            return "3";
        }
    }
    // if the user selects scissors
    else if (choice1 == "scissors") {
        if (choice2 == "rock") {
            return "2";
        }
    } else {
        return "3";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Escobear! The problem is that you do not return anything from your tie section, but restarts the game. At some point that will come back to you, and try to alert an undefined.

I think I would do something like this:

```js
// comparison between user and computer NOTE: This method is global, but it seemed pointless to redefine it for every game
function compare(choice1, choice2) {
  // if both selections are the same
  if (choice1 == choice2) {
    return -1;
  }

  // if the user selects rock
  else if (choice1 == "rock") {
    if (choice2 == "scissors") {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  // if the user selects scissors
  else if (choice1 == "scissors") {
    if (choice2 == "rock") {
      return 0;
    }
    return 1;
  }

  else if (choice1 == "paper") {
    if (choice2 == "rock") {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0
  }
};

// the game starts here
function startGame() {
  // the user
  var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

  // if invalid input
  while ((userChoice != "rock") && (userChoice != "paper") && (userChoice != "scissors")) {
    userChoice = prompt("Please select again, this time correctly!");
  }

  alert("You chose " + userChoice);

  // computer
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }
  alert("Computer pick: " + computerChoice);

  var result = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);

  if (result === -1) {
    alert('Tie, restart the game!');
    startGame();
  } else {
    alert(result ? 'You have won the game!' : 'LOOOOOSSSEEER!');
  }
}

startGame();
```

(I have also corrected some of the logic for winning, and added user input = paper)